# preg_match - getting position of regex match in the matched string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, match

So I know if you pass in the flag PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE you get the index of the regex match in the orginal "haystack", but what if I want the index of the match within the whole match?

Simple example:

Original String: `"Have a <1 + 2> day today"`

My regular expression `/<1 ([+|-]) 2>/`

So in the example I am matching whatever symbol is between the 1 and 2. If I did this in preg_match with the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag, the index for the matched symbol would be 10. I really would like it to return 3 though.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only way is to substract the whole pattern offset (7) to the capturing group offset (10): 10-7=3

```
$group_offset = $matches[1][1] - $matches[0][1];
```

Comment: Where are you getting a 3 dimensional array from? I always just get back a 2 dimensional array

Comment: @user1513171: sorry, i have used preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more tricky way by using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback):

```
$string = 'I have a <1 + 2> day today and a foo <4 - 1> week.';
$match = array();

preg_replace_callback('/<\d+ ([+|-]) \d+>/', function($m)use(&$match){
    $match[] = array($m[0], $m[1], strpos($m[0], $m[1]));
}, $string); // PHP 5.3+ required (anonymous function)
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <1 + 2>
            [1] => +
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <4 - 1>
            [1] => -
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```